# How do I disable back navigation and remove the back arrow on a Fragment, using Android Jetpack's Navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

> I am using Google's recommended single activity pattern with Android
>   Jetpack's Navigation component.

Fragment 1 is an authentication screen. After the user is authenticated and navigates to Fragment 2, I would like to make pressing of the Android back button close the app, and remove the back arrow in the app bar.

I have found methods, like `onBackPressedDispatcher`, to add / remove functionality from the back press, but nothing that also removes the back arrow.

I have also tried `app:popUpTo="@+id/firstFragment"` when navigating from Fragment 1 to Fragment 2, but that doesn't work either.

This should be possible to specify with a single line of code. Still trying to find. Any tips?

Comment: this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670377/8914336

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to remove `fragment1` from `back-stack` when navigation to `fragment2`

**fragment1**

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/fragment1"
android:name="packagenameforFragment1"
android:label="fragment1"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_1" >
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_Fragment1_to_Fragment2"
    app:destination="@id/Fragment2_id"
    app:launchSingleTop="true"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/your_MainGraph_id"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

then when you navigate from fragment1 to fragment2 call this

```
findNavController(fragment).navigate(R.id.action_Fragment1_to_Fragment2)
```

to remove the back button from Fragment2 you can use this

**in Activity onCreate()**

```
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration
        .Builder(R.id.your_fragment2_id,R.id.any_other_ids_you_want)
        .build()
```

then setup your toolbar like this

```
setupActionBarWithNavController(this, yourNavController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it achieves removing the back arrow from fragment2 and the back button closing the app from fragment2. However, I found that I also needed to add my fragment1 ID to the appBarConfiguration, otherwise it would show a back arrow on fragment1.

Comment: @mohammed great solution as long as you don't have a DrawerLayout. Otherwise it will show instead of back button, but stick act as a back button. It gets messy.

Comment: @Houman I think in that case you can use `addOnDestinationChangedListener` and show an hide the action-bar controls check https://stackoverflow.com/a/62028322

Comment: What if I go from fragment 2 to 3 and want the toolbar and I am using only one activity for whole app?

Comment: @JPM As mentioned above, you can fragment 2 and fragment 3 in appBarConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, you must setup appBarConfiguration manually.
Like mine.

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
    R.id.nav_home,
    R.id.nav_safety,
    R.id.nav_myskin,
    R.id.nav_setting
  ))
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Full code:

```
package limitless.android.uvindex.ui.activity

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import limitless.android.uvindex.R
import limitless.android.uvindex.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import limitless.android.uvindex.utils.Utils

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

        // Get the NavController
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        binding.bnv.setupWithNavController(navController)
        navController.graph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.nav_home,
            R.id.nav_safety,
            R.id.nav_myskin,
            R.id.nav_setting
        ))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_premium -> {
                Utils.startActivity(this, Intent(this, PremiumActivity::class.java))
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

}
```

The Resualt:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXCxB.png)